# Why use `Buffer.concat(body).toString();` instead of `Uint8Array/Buffer.toString()`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading [this article](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body) about gathering request data and it gives the following example:

```
var body = [];
request.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', function() {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
});
```

Other tutorials suggest this way:

```
var total = [];
request.on('data', function(chunk) {
  total += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
  body = total.toString();
  // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
});
```

They seem to be equivalent. Why use more elaborate `Buffer.concat(body).toString();` then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why use `Buffer.concat(body).toString();` instead of `UintArray8.toString()`?

Because they're doing [totally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/toString) [different](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) things. But that's not your real question, `chunk` is a `Buffer` as well not an `Uint8Array`.

> The two ways of gathering request data seem to be equivalent. What's the difference?

The second snippet is absolutely horrible code. Don't use it. First of all, it should have been written like this:

```
var total = "";
request.on('data', function(chunk) {
  total += chunk.toString();
}).on('end', function() {
  // at this point, `total` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
});
```

Starting with an array is absolute nonsense if you're doing string concatenation on it, and `total.toString()` was only necessary for the case that there were no `data` events. `total` would better be a string right from the beginning. In `chunk.toString()`, the explicit method call is unnecessary (omitting it would have led to it being called implicitly), but I wanted to show what happens here.

Now, how is converting the `chunk` buffers to strings and concatenating them different from collecting the buffers in an array, concatenating them to a big buffer and converting that to a string?

The answer is multiple-byte characters. Depending on the encoding and body text, there might be characters that are represented by multiple bytes. It can happen that those bytes come to lie across the border of two chunks (in subsequent `data` events). With the code that decodes each chunk separately, you'll get an invalid result in those cases.

Comment: thanks, I think this _The answer is multiple-byte characters_ is what I'm looking for. Can you please provide a simple example?

Comment: @Maximus `Buffer.concat([new Buffer([0xe2]), new Buffer([0x98, 0xba])]).toString() != "" + new Buffer([0xe2]) + new Buffer([0x98, 0xba])` (like `'☺' != '���'`)

Comment: I see, thanks. Isn't it better to append bits from the `chunck` to the `body` instead of storing them as multiple arrays?

Comment: @Maximus `body` is *one* array of buffers, exactly what `Buffer.concat` expects. Continously appending to one big buffer is probably inefficient because of copy-on-grow.

Comment: I've asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358449/transforming-text-to-uppercase) which I think is relevant to the matter explained by you here, can you please take a look?