# Transforming text to uppercase

Tags: node.js, stream, transform

I've found an example of a transform stream [here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html#what_are_transform_streams_) that transforms text to uppercase:

```
Upper.prototype._transform = function (chunk, enc, cb) {
  var upperChunk = chunk.toString().toUpperCase();
  this.push(upperChunk);
  cb();
};
```

Is my understanding correct that such approach might lead to errors when multi-byte encoding is used because a character bytes can be split between two chunks?

Wouldn't it be better to gather all chunks and then on `end` transform them? Something like this (not sure it'll work)

```
var body = [];
request.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', function() {
  this.push(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
});
```

Is `transform` function not used in this case?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. However, the proposed solution is [exactly the wrong of the two snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40238063/1048572).

Comment: Instead of waiting with all chunks for the end of the streams would be pretty inefficient. Rather, a buffer should be implemented that is pushed to on `data` events, and which will be consumed character-by-character.

Comment: thanks, sorry, used the wrong snippet. updated. what you're saying with the second comment is that `chunk` should always contain full characters?

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed that `chunk` always contains full characters, but it is possible to write a stream transformer that takes care of that - while still using chunked streaming, not trivially just waiting for the end.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. What about my this question _Is `transform` function not used in this case_?